# Type check doesn't work in generic class, but works in its derived class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm creating an `Emitter` class and I want to supply valid events via a type parameter:

```
type Events = {
    [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => void
}

class Emitter<T extends Events> {
    emit<K extends keyof T> (name: K, ...args: Parameters<T[K]>) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then, I extend this class and declare a type for its events. However, I want *its* derived classes to also be able to add events *on top*, so I have a type parameter here as well:

```
type AEvents = {
    update: (progress: number) => void
}

class A<T extends AEvents> extends Emitter<T> {
    action () {
        this.emit('update', 42) // Argument of type '[42]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<T["update"]>'. ts(2345)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I get an error when trying to call the `emit()` method. However, if I create class `B` derived from `A` and extend its events type, it works as expected:

```
type BEvents = AEvents & {
    foo: (input: string) => void
}

class B extends A<BEvents> {
    action () {
        this.emit('update', 42) // works as expected
        this.emit('foo', 'test') // works as expected
    }
}
```

You can also check this [in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFA3gWAFACQA2gNYQgBcUKwATgJaIDmAulQBQB03AhrUyio9EIIiwCUGAHxQ4Ae3oATfAF98+AMYAbHijQwAtvWDAItADwAVKBAAepxIv0JkKGbkIQjwcwGkb9khOUGQgcgBmUJYy7Ig8BhBUvgA0UNycfAJUAAp88RCmtChWRL4sUpIeBAQA9DVp3PgEangt+KCQUACC8EioGNhNAK5gijymHGC0cky0EHpUiEMGAEZmkugy8kqq6njaumhdVgEOwT0uqDJ2Z-rehVbuTTwawPRyiFDslU0EwAAW9BQnC8xnYAHIRmNTODUgAWABMkjq3X4yz6UAiUA60HBRERLHBUCBUEQcmAUEO9CYcRWWmgwDkUDAeQShUxkRxUHBuVo+UKxUsRAARFDxhBheVwZxsSh2AiAMxwgCs4iaLTaeC5ACFeq4Bhc+mgAGSDQjhORyDiMMBDYBUGgMZgbLYKZStPYHPRQbWnIJHcy6y5uM0EF5vD5fH6EP6A4Gg4AQsUw+FIqAogDucloJDQugCkFeEHd1QBQJB3ghFrksO5pho4OR9SzObzaDshdMJY1+CAA).

Why does that happen? How can I make the `emit()` call in class `A` valid?

---

**Edit:** Also, if I remove the type parameter from `A`, [it works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFA3gWAFACQA2gNYQgBcUKwATgJaIDmAulQBQB03AhrUyio9EIIiwCUGAHxQ4Ae3oATfAF98+AMYAbHijQwAtvWDAItADwAVKBAAepxIv0JkKGbkIQjwcwGkb9khOUGQgcgBmUJYy7Ig8BhBUvgA0UNycfAJUAAp88RCmtChWRL4sUpIeBAQA9DVp3PgEangt+KCQUACC8EioGNhNAK5gijymHGC0cky0EHpUiEMGAEZmkugy8kqq6njaumhdAQ7BhsaF5j0uqO5NPBrA9HKIUOyVTQTAABb0KJxeYzsADkIzGpmBqQALAAmSR1KAaOS0OaPT4-P4A7wgsHjCCQqDA8JyOTA+H1Lr8ZZ9KARKAdaDAgBExLkTOBUD+UEQcmAUEO9CYcRWWmgwDkUDAeQShVpkQZhKWqzMwM4TRaKiAA):

```
type AEvents = {
    update: (progress: number) => void
}

class A extends Emitter<AEvents> {
    action () {
        this.emit('update', 42) // correct
        this.emit('update', 'foo') // Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2:** This also [doesn't work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFA3gWAFACQA2gNYQgBcUKwATgJaIDmAulQBQB03AhrUyio9EIIiwCUGAHxQ4Ae3oATfAF98+AMYAbHijQwAtvWDAItADwAVKBAAepxIv0JkKGbkIQjwcwGkb9khOUGQgcgBmUJYy7Ig8BhBUvgA0UNycfAJUAAp88RCmtChWRL4sUpIeBAQA9DVp3PgEangt+KCQUACC8EioGNhNAK5gijymHGC0cky0EHpUiEMGAEZmkugy8kqq6njaumhdVjJ2DsGGxoVWUABk3b2u7k08GsD0cohQ7JVNBMAAC3oKE4XmM7AA5CMxqYIakACwAJnETRaLSAA):

```
type AEvents = {
    update: (progress: number) => void
}

class A<T> extends Emitter<T & AEvents> {
    action () {
        this.emit('update', 42) // Argument of type '[42]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<(T & AEvents)["update"]>'.
    }
}
```

Comment: Smells like a bug.

Comment: Not sure if this can be fixed, the problem seems to be that the mapped types cannot be resolved directly, i remember having seen a similar case to this in the past. If you look at the resolved type of emit you get `Parameters<T["update"]>` for the args rather than the expected `[number]`, so there is something preventing the compiler from resolving this due to the generic parameter.